# android message box layout implementation

Tags: android, xml

I was trying to implement a message box similar with that of Hangout. I want the edittext to expand if more content is typed into it, with the button to the right **remain at the bottom right corner.**

[image: Message box from Hangout]

My current implement is as follows. The button to the right will move up if the edit text expands due to "alignParentTop". But if I set "alignParentBottom" as true, the entire screen will get occupied by this relative layout. Any idea how to fix it

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/structured_relative_interaction"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#E0E0E0">

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/structured_imagebutton_takePhoto"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/save_structured_button"
        android:src="@drawable/take_photo"/>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/structured_edittext_answer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/structured_imagebutton_takePhoto"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/structured_hint"
        android:textColorHint="#B0B0B0"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine">
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve it using the following layout (some ids for images and strings were changed to make it compileable):

```
<!--suppress AndroidLintUselessParent, AndroidLintContentDescription -->
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/structured_relative_interaction"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#E0E0E0">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/structured_edittext_answer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/structured_imagebutton_takePhoto"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:hint="hint"
            android:textColorHint="#B0B0B0"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/structured_imagebutton_takePhoto"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/structured_edittext_answer"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Will produce:

[image]

Seems it's common issue with `ExitText` and `RelativeLayout` (at least, I've seen some similar questions previously).

Comment: looks great! will try it later!

Answer (score 0):

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/write_post"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="85dip"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="@string/write_post"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >
        </EditText>
```

set android:inputType to textMultiLine, android automatically expands edittext if the text exceeds from its boundry.